# How to implement gate which is like Identity but multiplied on "i"

Tags: quantum-gate, experimental-realization

In my program I need a single qubit processing gate which implements logic like this:
|0>  ==> i*|0>
|1>  ==> i*|1>

This is like Identity gate but multiplied on "i"

I belive that conversion matrix 2x2 should be like this:
**i,  0

0,  i**

But do not know if such gate exists.
How to implement it is qiskit program or in IMB quantum composer?
Can this be possible?

Comment: *Why* do you need this gate? If it's really for applying to a single qubit, then the $i$ is just a global phase and it makes no observable difference, so you don't actually need to apply it. If you're actually wanting to apply a controlled version of this gate that's a different question (one which has been asked and answered several times on this site).

Comment: There is a schema I found in article https://eslitak.livejournal.com/249152.html and this schema has gate [iI] which is that "iI". I want to reproduce this schema in qiskit program and do experiments but I met this issue I do not know how to implement [iI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the identity X•Y•Z = i•I to implement your operation. Just do a Z then a Y then an X. Target them all on the same qubit; it doesn't matter which one.

It's likely you're confused about needing this operation, because it's effect is unobservable unless it is controlled. And if it's controlled it's just equivalent to an S gate on the control.

Comment: I tried Your proposition and it really works - I mean I see "i" multiplier appear. Besides that, now I also agree that seem this operator makes no sense, as everybody says to me. I asked for this operator because article I use for study (https://eslitak.livejournal.com/248861.html) reffers this gate. But in my experiments I see that i can safily remove it from schema proposed by article author. Result of schema is exactly same with or without [iI] gate.